# Hypothesis test shows a significant difference in variances. Is the difference is big or small?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Two sample test of hypothesis for comparing two variances shows the following result:

```
Null hypothesis         σ(Param A) / σ(Param B) = 1
Alternative hypothesis  σ(Param A) / σ(Param B) ≠ 1
Significance level      α = 0.05
```

Statistics

```
                                          95% CI for
Variable            N  StDev  Variance      StDevs
Param A         47091  0.100     0.010  (0.100, 0.101)
Param B         47091  0.102     0.010  (0.101, 0.103)

Ratio of standard deviations = 0.982
Ratio of variances = 0.964
```

95% Confidence Intervals

```
                            CI for
         CI for StDev      Variance
Method       Ratio           Ratio
Bonett  (0.973, 0.991)  (0.947, 0.982)
Levene  (    *,     *)  (    *,     *)
```

Tests

```
                         Test
Method  DF1    DF2  Statistic  P-Value
Bonett    1      —      15.89    0.000
Levene    1  94180       3.15    0.076
```

Based on the -
p-Value, I can conclude that there is a significant difference.

How do I conclude if the difference is significantly big or small?

I guess I am missing a theory here, 
I would appreciate if someone leads me to the right way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Bonett test is applicable, you are correct that the small P-value `0.000` (meaning $<0.0005$) indicates that the two population SDs differ "significaantly" (their ratio differs from 1).

The corresponding 95% CI says that $0.973 \le \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2} \le 0.991,$ which indicates a small difference between the two population SDs. Notice that the CI does not contain $1.$
More directly, the sample SDs are $S_1 = 0.100$ and $S_2 = 0.102.$

The population variances in your computer output are rounded too much so that
there does not appear to be any difference between them. If the sample SDs
are correct to three places, then the sample variances *are* a little different: $S_1^2 = 0.0100$ and $S_2^2 = 0.0104.$

The very large sample sizes have enabled you to detect, as statistically
significant, a very small difference between the two sample SDs.

Whether the small difference between $S_1 = 0.100$ and $S_2 = 0.102$ is of any
*practical* importance is not really a statistical question. That is for
the experimenters to decide, based on their knowledge of the data and
what is being measured.

**Addendum per Comments:**
If you are testing $H_0: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2 = 1$ against 
$H_a: \sigma_1^2/\sigma_2^2 \ne 1$ at the 5% level, using $F = S_1^2/S_2^2$
as the test statistic, then you will reject if $F < 0.9868$ or $F > 1.0182$.
For your data $F = 0.9612 < 0.9868,$ so you reject because $F$ is below
the lower critical value. Below is output from R statistical software for $F$ based on the computer
printout above and a computation of the critical values. I show output from
software because F values for such large samples as yours are not explicitly
printed in tables of the F distribution.

```
f = (.100/.102)^2;  f
## 0.9611688
qf(.025, 47090, 47090)   # lower critical value
## 0.982098
qf(.975, 47090, 47090)   # upper critical value
## 1.018228
```

Comment: Thank you Bruce, some more questions are still disturbing me... 1) How do you know: "If the sample SDs are correct to three places, then the sample variances are a little different"? 2) My supervisor said, that to conclude if the difference big or small, I need to calculate the F left and right critical values depending on N1, N2 ,... as in http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda359.htm  but how would one calculate these F critical values.3) Did you base your conclusion following the same idea? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) Square the SDs. 2) Unclear what criterion for 'big' vs 'small'. Will give F critical values some thought. Are you using F-tables or software? 3) Based my conclusion to Reject on output for Bonett P-value. // More after coffee and breakfast.

Comment: I do not understand exactly what your supervisor is looking for. But I have made an Addendum to my Answer with the critical values you asked for  --
 in accordance with the NIST handbook you referenced.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a nice explanation, Bruce! I really appreciate it! Thanks again!!!